# Why is filter based on dependent pair?

Tags: idris

In the [Idris Tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html) a function for filtering vectors is based on dependent pairs.

```
filter : (a -> Bool) -> Vect n a -> (p ** Vect p a)
filter f [] = (_ ** [])
filter f (x :: xs) with (filter f xs )
  | (_ ** xs') = if (f x) then (_ ** x :: xs') else (_ ** xs')
```

But why is it necessary to put this in terms of a dependent pair instead of something more direct such as?

```
filter' : (a -> Bool) -> Vect n a -> Vect p a
```

In both cases the type of `p` must be determined, but in my supposed alternative the redundancy of listing `p` twice is eliminated.

My naive attempts at implementing `filter'` failed, so I was wondering is there a fundamental reason that it can't be implemented? Or can `filter'` be implemented, and perhaps `filter` was just a poor example to showcase dependent pairs in Idris? But if that is the case then in what situations would dependent pairs be useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kim Stebel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677414/614394) is right on the money. Let me just note that this was already discussed on the Idris mailing list back in 2012 (!!):

- [filter for vector, a question - Idris Programming Language](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/idris-lang/7L4OnI0tvEg/gpaiya1aklkJ)

What [raichoo](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/idris-lang/7L4OnI0tvEg/57nFAiaFHe4J) posted there can help clarifying it I think; the *real* signature of your `filter'` is

```
filter' : {p : Nat} -> {n: Nat} -> {a: Type} -> (a -> Bool) -> Vect a n -> Vect a p
```

from which it should be obvious that this is *not* what filter should (or even could) do; `p` actually *depends* on the predicate and the vector you are filtering, and you can (actually need to) express this using a dependent pair. Note that in the pair `(p ** Vect p a)`, `p` (and thus `Vect p a`) implicitly depends on the (unnamed) predicate and vector appearing before it in its signature.

Expanding on this, why a dependent pair? You want to return a vector, but there's no "`Vector` with unknown length" type; you need a length *value* for obtaining a `Vector` type. But then you can just think "OK, I will return a `Nat` together with a vector with that length". The type of this pair is, unsurprisingly, an example of a dependent pair. In more detail, a dependent pair `DPair a P` is a type built out of

1. A type `a`
2. A function `P: a -> Type`

A value of that type `DPair a P` is a *pair* of values

1. `x: a`
2. `y: P a`

At this point I think that is just syntax what might be misleading you. The type `p ** Vect p a` *is* `DPair Nat (\p => Vect p a)`; `p` there is not a parameter for filter or anything like it. All this can be a bit confusing at first; if so, maybe it helps thinking of `p ** Vect p a` as a substitute for the "`Vector` with unknown length" type.

Comment: I now see why `filter'` cannot be, thanks. But I don't think it has been covered here (or in the mailing list) as to why the original definition doesn't suffer the same as my alternative. That is, why isn't there also an implicit `{p:Nat}` in the original definition allowing the caller to specify the return length? I suppose you are getting to this in your last sentence, but I don't quite understand, could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, added a more detailed explanation about why you need dependent pairs.

Answer (score 13):

The difference between `filter` and `filter'` is between existential and universal quantification. If `(a -> Bool) -> Vect n a -> Vect p a` was the correct type for `filter`, that would mean `filter` returns a Vector of  length p and the caller can specify what p should be.

Comment: And it's obvious that we cannot produce a vector of an *arbitrary* length for an *arbitrary* type. Let us consider the following case: the input vector is `[]` and `a` is an uninhabited type, but that means we cannot produce a vector for a *non-zero* `p`, because we must provide at least one element `x` of type `a`, and the input does *not* provide us with that. So, indeed, `filter'` cannot be implemented in this general setting.

Comment: Thanks Kim, but how does DPair prevent this behavior?

Comment: A dependent pair is like saying, "there is a p, such that...", but the caller can't specify what p is

Comment: Would it be more accurate to switch the order of "universal" and "existential" to match the order of `filter` and `filter'`? `filter` is existential, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but additional context

Idris 1 documentation - https://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#dependent-pairs

Idris 2 documentation - https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html?highlight=dependent#dependent-pairs

In Idris 2 the dependent pair defined [here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/523c0a6d7823d2b9a614d4a30efb52da015f9367/libs/prelude/Builtin.idr#L84-L98)

and is similar to [`Exists`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/523c0a6d78/libs/base/Data/DPair.idr#L33-L36) and [`Subset`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/523c0a6d78/libs/base/Data/DPair.idr#L70-L73) but BOTH  of it's values are NOT erased at runtime